# how to fix the error that show index.html:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '%'

Tags: javascript, string, function, bootstrap-4, javascript-objects

index.html:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '%' (at index.html:1:14)

this error show when i change this code

```
function templateComment(item, postInfo, conditionComment) {
  console.log(conditionComment)
  const comm = `
    <div class="comment pb-1" onclick=${!conditionComment ? `showUserInfo(${encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(postInfo))})` : 'showUserInfo(null)'}>
          <div class="pt-1 flex align-items-center justify-content-center gap-3 pb-1">
          ${typeof item.author.profile_image === "string" ?
      `<img src="${item.author.profile_image}" alt="Avatar1" class="img-fluid my-1" style="width: 30px; height: 30px; border-radius: 50% !important;" />`
      :
      `<img src="images/icons8-user-48.png" alt="Avatar2" class="img-fluid my-1" style="width: 30px; height: 30px; border-radius: 50% !important;" />`
    }                     
          <span><strong>@${item.author.username}</strong></span>
          </div>
          <h5>${item.body}</h5>
        </div>
      `;
  return comm;
}
export default templateComment;
```

```
 <div class="comment pb-1" onclick=${!conditionComment ? `showUserInfo(${encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(postInfo))})` : 'showUserInfo(null)'}>
```

the error come when i change this line

so what this error mean and how to slove this error ??

Comment: You would need to wrap your function parameters as an actual string. Try adding quotes before and after the function parameters. Meaning your `onclick` would then be looking like: 

`onclick=${!conditionComment ? \`showUserInfo("${encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(postInfo))}")\` : 'showUserInfo(null)'}`